VBA's .CopyPicture generate picture with blurry fonts for no reason
VBA's .CopyPicture generate picture with blurry fonts for no reason, I use identical scripts for other file, and it works fine. This script generates two pictures from two ranges and paste it into an email, the first picture always comes out with "blurry" fonts like shown below:
Example

Sub RLHSd()
Dim FilePath As String
Dim Outlook As Object
Dim OutlookMail As Object
Dim HTMLBody As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim Rng3 As Range
Dim dtToday As String
Dim lRow2 As Long
Dim lRow As Long
Dim oWB As Workbook
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim Wd As String
Dim Wd2 As String
Dim Ws As Worksheet


' Open Inbase Template


Set oWB = Workbooks.Open("\\DailyReports\Template\XXXXX.xlsm")
Set WB = Workbooks.Open("\\DailyReports\Template\YYYYYY.xlsm")
Set Ws = WB.Sheets("ZZZZZZ")

' Update
WB.Sheets("Raw").ListObjects("Raw_2").QueryTable.Refresh False

WB.RefreshAll

Ws.EnableCalculation = False
Ws.EnableCalculation = True

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:13"))

' Today
dtToday = GetPreviousDay(Now) - 1

' Width

Wd = WB.Sheets("ZZZZZZ").Range("J364").Value
Wd2 = WB.Sheets("ZZZZZZ").Range("J421").Value


' Rng

Application.CutCopyMode = False


Set rng = WB.Sheets("ZZZZZZ").Range("A365:" & Wd & "410")
Set rng2 = WB.Sheets("ZZZZZZ").Range("A425:" & Wd2 & "470")

Call createImage("ZZZZZZ", rng.Address, "RangeImage")
Call createImage("ZZZZZZ", rng2.Address, "RangeImage2")



' Off
With Application
.Calculation = xlManual
.ScreenUpdating = False
.EnableEvents = False
End With


' Mail
Set Outlook = CreateObject("outlook.application")
Set OutlookMail = Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

FilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
HTMLBody = "<span LANG=EN>" _
& "" _
& "Dear A," _
& "<br>" _
& "Please find MTD result of ZZZZZZ as of " & dtToday & ":<br> " _
& "<br>" _
& "<img src='cid:RangeImage.jpg'>" _
& "<img src='cid:RangeImage2.jpg'>" _
& "<br>Regards</font></span>"

With OutlookMail
.Subject = "ZZZZZZ as of " & dtToday
.HTMLBody = HTMLBody
.Attachments.Add FilePath & "RangeImage.jpg", olByValue
.Attachments.Add FilePath & "RangeImage2.jpg", olByValue
.To = " "
.CC = " "
.Display

End With

oWB.Close

' On
With Application
.Calculation = xlAutomatic
.ScreenUpdating = True
.EnableEvents = True
End With





End Sub
Sub createImage(SheetName As String, rngAddrss As String, nameFile As String)
Dim rngJpg As Range
Dim Shape As Shape

' F
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


 
On Error Resume Next
Do
        Err.Clear
 
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Worksheets(SheetName).Activate
Set rngJpg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Range(rngAddrss)
rngJpg.CopyPicture
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).ChartObjects.Add(rngJpg.Left, rngJpg.Top, rngJpg.Width, rngJpg.Height)
.Activate
For Each Shape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
Shape.Line.Visible = msoFalse
Next
.Chart.Paste
.Chart.Export Environ$("temp") & "\" & nameFile & ".jpg", "JPG"
End With
Worksheets(SheetName).ChartObjects(Worksheets(SheetName).ChartObjects.Count).Delete
Set rngJpg = Nothing
 
Loop Until Err.Number = 0
 
 
End Sub
Function GetPreviousDay(RptDate As Date) As String
    Dim PreviousDay As Date
    ' Check if the current day is the first of the month
    If Day(RptDate) = 1 Then
        ' If it is, get the last day of the previous month
        PreviousDay = DateSerial(Year(RptDate), Month(RptDate) - 1, 0)
    Else
        ' Otherwise, get the previous day
        PreviousDay = RptDate - 1
    End If
    ' Format the date as YYYYMMDD
    GetPreviousDay = Format(PreviousDay, "YYYYMMDD")
End Function





How do I avoid this?

CopyPicture takes arguments - have you tried specifying those?

@TimWilliams Sorry, I don't get what you mean, I am new to this.

Please, try rngJpg.CopyPicture  xlScreen, xlBitmap. If not improved, try rngJpg.CopyPicture  xlPrinter, xlBitmap. Look here to see what Microsoft says about this method.

@FaneDuru thanks for helping but the first method didn't change anything while the second method (xlPrinter, xlBitmap) freezed and crashed Excel

xlPrinter is a constant (2) and  xlScreen = 1. Did you look to the link I pasted? You did not tag the used application. Don't you use Excel? If not, these constants have a meaning only in Excel. Otherwise, you should use the constants themselves. Do you have Option Explicit on top of the respective module? Otherwise, you maybe wrongly copied them.. I mean, their spelling... Without Option Explicit the not declared variables will be considered 0 it the method expects something numeric.

@FaneDuru OK, I tried Option Explicit and
"rngJpg.CopyPicture Appearance:=1, Format:=2"
It still doesn't work, this time both pictures turn into blanks. I am using Excel 365, but still thanks for helping

And "rngJpg.CopyPicture Appearance:=2, Format:=2" will still freeze excel for no reason

@EdK you may remove (for testing) On error resume next and check if you get an error.

@Shrotter I added "Loop Until Err.Number = 0" because sometimes the Sub createImage fail to copy the shape to clipboard, I use the loop to force it to repeat the process
